# Run multiple docker-compose (one per machine)

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-machine

I'm testing a lot of micro-services. 
I group some of them in a docker-compose file like:

```
agent:
  image: php:fpm
  volumes:
    - ./GIT:/reposcm:ro
  expose:
    - 9000
  links:
    - elastic

elastic:
  image: elasticsearch
  expose:
    - 9200
    - 9300
```

Then I start the first one by `$docker-compose up`

In another directory I would start another "micro-service" by `$docker-compose up`. But I get:

```
ERROR: Couldn't connect to Docker daemon - you might need to run `docker-machine start default`.
```

How can I specify the docker machine for a docker-compose.yml?

```
$docker-machine ls
NAME      ACTIVE   DRIVER       STATE     URL                         SWARM
default   -        virtualbox   Running   tcp://192.168.99.101:2376
my_test   -        virtualbox   Running   tcp://192.168.99.102:2376
```

Only the `default` machine can run a "micro-service".

How can I specify a target machine of a `docker-compose.yml`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Make sure that, in the shell you want to run your second docker-compose up, you have done first a [docker-machine env](https://docs.docker.com/machine/reference/env/):

```
docker-machine env <machine name>
eval "$(docker-machine env <machine name>)
```

That will configure the [right environment variables](https://github.com/docker/compose/blob/12af889e26f1c8320632f3ced94995f428e93325/docs/production.md#running-compose-on-a-single-server) for docker commands to contact the right machine (the right docker daemon).

Comment: Thx! 
Moreover, after `docker-machine env <machine name>`, I had to run `eval "$(docker-machine env <machine name>)"`